# How to get a clear concept of React key property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been using ReactJS recently but when it comes to "key" property I really don't know how it works.

Say in parent component I do render like :

```
render: function() {

  // dataList = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];  => initial state
  // dataList = [{id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];  => second dataList state

  var someComponentList = [];

  this.state.dataList.forEach(function(data) {
    someComponentList.push(
      <SomeComponent key={data.id} id={data.id}/>
      )
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {someComponentList}
    </div>
    )
}
```

In SomeComponent :

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function({
        // Render work here
    }),
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        console.log(this.props.id == nextProps.id);
    }
})
```

So in `componentWillReceiveProps` I expect 3 `false` console result (which I do if I didn't give `key` attribute to `<SomeComponent>`) after `setState()` but actually I have only 1 false because ReactJs seems to know that `{id: 2}` & `{id: 3}` are identical even they're given in different order in `dataList` state

I found some brief documentation on Reactjs official :

> When React reconciles the keyed children, it will ensure that any child with key will be reordered (instead of clobbered) or destroyed (instead of reused).

can somebody explain how it works?

Comment: It looks like your `componentWillReceiveProps` is on the parent component, not on `SomeComponent`

Answer (score 5):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

> If you specify a key, React is now able to find insertion, deletion,
>   substitution and moves in O(n) using a hash table.

It's just a simple hash table (of siblings) lookup, and makes React try to reuse components that have the same key.

A rough explanation,
without keys:
[1] [2] [3]
[2] [3] [4]
list-wise diff, [updateAttributes x3]
with keys:
[1] [2] [3] nil
nil [2] [3] [4]
list of [2] [3] [4], [2] has key matching with [2] no changes, [3] has key ... [3] no changes, [4] has no key and no more nodes in original list so insert, [1] will be destroyed